# Use different CSS stylesheets for the same page

Tags: php, css

Am I able to use two different CSS stylesheets in the same page, but make my page not read the second, for example?

I have my PHP code, and one stylesheet. Inside my PHP code I've included a Custom Header and that has another CSS file, but that CSS is not applied to the rest of page.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You can use [scoped css](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped) but this is not available for all browsers

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean; can you show some of your code to illustrate your issue? If I understand it correctly, you want to use one CSS file only for a single php file you include but make the other CSS file apply to everything else. Unfortunately, this does not work as php will only generate a single HTML output in which everything would then be, making both CSS files apply at the same time. So if you want to apply styles only to one part of the site, you need to do this with CSS rules; that’s not a php problem though.

Comment: I assume you have one page that has to use e.g. `complete-page.css`. Then on the page you have a module, that is included via php, for what different css rules has to apply. In that case you can wrap the content of the module in a container having a certain css class. https://jsfiddle.net/tobd3txu/

Comment: Poke. you got it. I will gave my second CSS to other person make his own css. 
So, just to know. I make al pages of my site, but the Header and Footer, will be defined for who buy our system. We try to use the iframe, but when you resize the window, we need to resize the property HEIGHT to... it ok to understanding what I say?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to affect anything else on the page just make sure it's using different ID's and classes to the other stylesheet.

Although I personally would follow the more sensible approach of just including all the CSS in one stylesheet. Unless you can explain specifically why you need them to be separate?

Comment: Ok, i know this, thank you. But i can't explain very well, let me try again.. The second CSS, will be write for another users... and they cant modify the first CSS, even if he copy the same class by inspect element. That is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow the whole chain of what is included, but if you prefix your CSS selectors (e.g. a [BEM](https://tech.yandex.com/bem/) style naming convention) for the included content, those selectors won't affect the rest of the page.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you. Just to know, the Header and Footer will be defined by our client. and i need to block him to modify our CSS (the first CSS). He can change/creat only for Header and Footer, nothing else...
I hope this BEM does it. TY.